# check vs checked for bucket list or todo list

Tags: word-choice, expression-choice

I want to express that something is done on my todo list or bucket list, in short written form.

Which is the more appropriate way, "**XXX, checked.**" or "**XXX, check.**"?

I understand that in oral form, "check" is more appropriate because it is literally the action that you are doing, but what about written form, where the action has been done?

Comment: Perhaps "checked" is more common in the UK tha in the US.  Or maybe in the UK they would even say "ticked" and not "checked".  I don't think you say "Item One, tick", though.

Comment: This has nothing to do with written vs oral form.  Either usage can exist in either form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check is used during a live assessment; if it has been completed in the past, it should already have been checked.

You could say "Item one; check" if you are assessing your list.

So you should say "Item one (is) checked" to describe its state at the time of your narrative.